# Webview with Google Play website freeze

Tags: android, webview, freeze

I got stuck on this problem the whole evening. I have a webview that opens up the google play publish site. I log in, it loads the framework, and then gets stuck with the "LOADING" text and progress circle image(frozen). It can stay like that for 2 minutes, and then just show everything perfectly normal. This is on my HTC Desire with Oxygene 2.3.2 (Android 2.3.7). **Also in the built-in browser the same thing happens. I discovered this after like 6 hours.**
When I run it on my Asus transformaer prime, it takes 1-2 seconds to show, perfectly normal, and an emulator with 2.2 runs it just fine.
I tried changing lots of things already, but still the same freeze on my Desire. I dont know what is so special with the google play site, that my android version cant handle. Anyone with similar experience???

My testing activity (made this up for this post).

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {

public final static boolean debug = true;
public final static String TAG    = "HELLOWORLD";

private WebView mWebView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String mURL = "https://play.google.com/apps/publish/Home";
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient( new MyWebViewClient() );
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
    mWebView.loadUrl(mURL);

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        if(debug)
            Log.i(TAG,"onPageStarted("+url+")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if(debug)
            Log.i(TAG,"onPageFinished("+url+")");
    }

}
}
```

**In main.xml**

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/mywebview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</WebView>
```

Comment: "Also in the built-in browser the same thing happens." I doubt there's anything we can do if even Android's browser chokes on it.

Comment: I came to that conclusion too, ceejayoz. I also asked if anyone have a similar experience (and maybe, just maybe, there is a workaround). I doubt it, but I must ask. Perhaps it is rom-specific. The thing is, I have an app with this webview in it, and also a complaint about it not working, so thats why I started investigating this. Im not alone with the problem. The one who complained has a Motorola  droid 4 with Android 2.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar thing with 4.0.4 version. it feels like it's a problem with network interface or network interface driver.
I tried running it on different emulators and one works fine while the other....NOT.
i think it is a specific thing to a specific machine/phone.

Comment: in future, you might want to add this kind of thing as a comment rather than as an answer